# Using AWS Fargate as web server

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

Using AWS Fargate, the process to get a custom Docker container running on AWS ECS is relatively straightforward.

I was able to successfully test my container over the public IP assigned to the network interface of the VPC that the Fargate cluster is hosted in; the container is a simple HTTP server listening on `0.0.0.0:80`.

I have also recently purchased a DNS domain using AWS Route53.

Now, I want to assign the DNS to the ECS service so instead of sending the request to a random IP address (which also changes with each update of the ECS service) I want to be able to send my requests directly to the root of my domain.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your website visitors are not supposed to talk directly to the Fargate container. As you realised the IPs are not predictable and can change at any time - it’d be difficult to keep the DNS up to date.

Instead use [**Application Load Balancer**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) in front of Fargate and use the ALB’s address for your website.

ALB will automatically register the Fargate containers as they come and go.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Okay, I was just testing the same, but with a *Network Load Balancer*. It works using the Amazon-provided domain. I also added a record to the public hosted zone that comes with the domain in Route53 (The hosted zone's name is the domain name followed by a dot) to redirect requests of type *A* to my load balancer. When I test the record it returns the correct IP - but in my browser the server couldn't be found. Do you know why?

Comment: @MarkusAppel Nope I don't know why. I would need more details about what's in your zone. Dare to share the actual domain name?

Comment: I actually got it working, deleting and recreating the record set resolved the issue - almost looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I suggested an edit.